# Why does my CSS stop working whenever I add "<!DOCTYPE html....."

Tags: html

I had some code that produced a table, and worked perfectly.

[image]

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>

<table>
<tr class="d0"><th>SCHED DATE<th>AMOUNT
<tr class="d0"><td style="text-align: left;">Aug 1, 2011</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>
<tr class="d1"><td style="text-align: left;">Jul 27, 2011</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>
<tr class="d0"><td style="text-align: left;">Jul 20, 2011</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>

<tr><td>Total:</td><td style="{border-top: grey thin solid; text-align: right;}">$300</td>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I added a line so that I could pass html validation at validator.w3.org

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

but that broke my CSS, the right format is gone, and my total line is gone

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: That's what you get for writing CSS in inline `style` attributes *before* adding the doctype declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following portion of your code looks strange :

```
<td style="{border-top: grey thin solid; text-align: right;}">
```

The `{}` arround the style's values doesn't seem quite standard *(and as you specified, with the `doctype` declaration, that you want the browser to interpret your code using a well-defined standard...)*

You should probably remove those `{}`, and use something like this -- which looks a bit more standard-compliant :

```
<td style="border-top: grey thin solid; text-align: right;">
```

Also, as noted by **@cthulhu**, you are opening `<tr>` and `<th>` tags, but never closing them :

- there is an opening `<tr>` at the beginning of each of the following lines *(and others)* :
- and you have two opening `<th>` tags on the first line :

```
<tr class="d0"><th>SCHED DATE<th>AMOUNT
<tr class="d0"><td style="text-align: left;">Aug 1, 2011</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>
<tr class="d1"><td style="text-align: left;">Jul 27, 2011</a></td><td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>
```

You should add closing `</th>` and `</tr>` tags where needed :

```
<tr class="d0">
    <th>SCHED DATE</th>
    <th>AMOUNT</th>
</tr>
<tr class="d0">
    <td style="text-align: left;">Aug 1, 2011</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="d1">
    <td style="text-align: left;">Jul 27, 2011</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">$100</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Also he should close properly `th`

Comment: @cthulhu true, I didn't see that -- I will edit my answer to add this ; thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

This breaks your css: `{border-top: grey thin solid; text-align: right;}`

Remove the surrounding `{}` and it should be ok again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change You first row to `<tr><th>SCHED DATE</th><th>AMOUNT</th></tr>`.
2. Remove the `{ ... }` in your style on the bottom row.

Answer (score 0):

You have broken HTML for the first row which contains the header. It should be:

```
<tr><th>SCHED DATE AMOUNT</th></tr>
```

Broken HTML probably cause the browser to "skip" rendering things and break the design.

Comment: Oh right I'm an idiot, the doctype is XHTML. The closing tags are OK to leave out in normal HTML, though.